# Where exactly are dialog text, OK button, and Cancel buttons defined or inherited from in CodenameOne?

Tags: dialog, codenameone

Where *exactly* are 1) dialog 'text', 2) dialog 'OK' button, and 3) dialog 'Cancel' button **defined** or **inherited from** in CodenameOne?

Where can I see the code which instructs a `dialog` to be made of those components? Can someone direct me to the base class, method, etc. where **each** of those 3 items are defined?

I am referring to a `Dialog` meaning `com.codename1.ui.Dialog`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest asking "how to do something" rather than "where something exists" as the answer to the latter might lead you to the wrong place.

E.g. in this case these things don't exist. All the static show methods in the `Dialog` eventually call into this uber method: 
https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/Dialog.java#L904-L940

You will notice that it constructs the components dynamically to create the dialog and doesn't provide the means to manipulate said components as the `Dialog` is static methods are meant to be very simple stateless tools.

Comment: Thanks. You gave me the answer I needed.